# How to reference Object that it has been already declared at the API level? (asp.net web-api)

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api2

I'm relatively new to asp.net Web API. I would like to know the following: Is there a way to reference an Object (Customer, Student, etc...) declared at the API level?

Let's say I'm going to consume the web-api from a console app. Once I make a call to the web api like this:

```
using(HttpResponseMessage response = ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(ApiHelper.ApiClient.BaseAddress).Result)
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<Student> hello = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Student>>();

                return hello;
            }
```

What is the best practice to reference Student that it has been already declared at the API level?

Compared to WCF, when the service-reference is added, you get the Objects/Entities declared at the service level. Is there something similar in asp.net web-api?

Comment: If `Student` is a common class used by multiple applications then I imagine it should be in a class library referenced by both applications.

Comment: I currently have it like that; ClassLibrary > Entities > Student... but my boss doesn't like it that way. He's more related to WCF and wants something similar; like referencing object straight from the web-api...

Comment: In that case you can still use WCF on the client to consume the REST service.  Though I don't know much about WCF and how it generates classes.  The service may need to expose some sort of schema of its operations in order for the consuming client to generate code.  ASP.NET WebAPI likely doesn't expose that by default, but there may be other tools to help with it.

Comment: @DevNgron You'll just have to educate him. Any major API that you work with (Google, Twilio, AWS, for example), you use their assemblies so you can reference their objects. Auto-generated proxy classes that are based on WSDL or something can be a major problem if the WSDL contains errors.

Comment: I found out a really good blog on which it basically states that (1) you should create a "Common Class Library", (2) define your DTOs there, (3) and reference from both: web api, and client... Here's reference to the blog if it helps any one out there https://exceptionnotfound.net/a-simple-organization-for-asp-net-web-api-producer-consumer-apps/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually:

1) Copy the Json/Xml text returned by your API.

2) Open Visual Studio and click in Edit > Paste Special > (Paste XML As Classes or Paste as JSON Classes).

Comment: That's certainly doable, but it's just a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: How frequently the services that you use changes it's result models?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good option always to create the Model response in the client-side if the Web API is an external resource that does not sure libraries with other projects that use the API.

In that way you'll avoid to use dynamic objects and the code will be more readable as well.